# How can I create a dual has_many relationship in Laravel?

Tags: database, model, migration, laravel, eloquent

I have a database with a Employee table and a Customer table. The Employee table has 2 one_to_many relationships with the Customer table; the foreign keys in the Customer table are 'primary_sales_contact_id' and 'primary_service_contact_id'. Both obviously refer to the id field on the Employee table.
How do I set up a migration for this, and how would I subsequently create a model for it? I'm a newbie in Laravel, so apologies if its blindingly obvious, and thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

**Employee migration**

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateEmpoyeeTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('employee', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('employee');
    }

}
```

**Customer migration**

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCustomerTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('customer', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('primary_sales_contact_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('primary_service_contact_id')->unsigned();

            $table->foreign('primary_sales_contact_id')->references('id')->on('employee');
            $table->foreign('primary_service_contact_id')->references('id')->on('employee');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('customer');
    }

}
```

**Employee model**

```php
class Employee extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'employee';

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function customersService() {
        return $this->hasMany('Customer', 'primary_service_contact_id');
    }

    public function customersSale() {
        return $this->hasMany('Customer', 'primary_sales_contact_id');
    }
}
```

**Customer model**

```php
class Customer extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'customer';

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function primarySalesContact() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Employee', 'primary_sales_contact_id');
    }

    public function primaryServiceContact() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Employee', 'primary_service_contact_id');
    }
}
```

All stuff use like:

```php
$customer = Customer::find(1);
echo $customer->primaryServiceContact;
$employee = Employee::find(1);
echo $employee->customersSale;
```

Comment: Thanks a million kr4Y; I knew it would be easy once I saw it. God, I love Laravel!